# How to style UTF arrow &#10148

Tags: css, html

I put UTF arrow &#10148 on my site and I have two questions:

1. How can I set the color?
2. Can I rotate it to be an up arrow?  I don't see an equivalent up arrow style for &#10148 in the UTF arrows.

Here's the code I'm using now:

```css
a.UTF_uparrow {
  font-size: 15pt;
  color: rgb(140, 173, 255);
}
```

```html
<a href="#bkmkAA" class="UTF_uparrow" style="text-decoration: none">&#10148;</a>
```

The color always defaults to a salmon color no matter what color I choose in the css code, unlike other page elements, and I want it to point up, not right.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Using `!important` in your css will make the color change?

Comment: !important color: rgb(140,173,255); does not do it, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: Please, google `css important`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:inline-block` or `block` then `transform:rotate(-90deg);`. The color is correct...do you still see a salmon color on this demo? If not then override the style by either trying `!important` (not recommended) or chain the class for higher specificity like so:

> ```
> a.UTF_uparrow.UTF_uparrow.UTF_uparrow {...
> ```

```css
a.UTF_uparrow {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15pt;
  color: rgb(140, 173, 255);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

a.small {
  font-size: 7pt;
}
```

```html
<a href="#bkmkAA" class="UTF_uparrow" style="text-decoration: none">&#10148;</a>

<a href="#bkmkAA" class="UTF_uparrow small" style="text-decoration: none">&#10148;</a>
```

Comment: that works to rotate it.  Thanks.  Now for the color . . .

Comment: Your demo shows the correct color, and the chain works for me too.  Thanks very much, that's the correct answer.

Comment: You are very welcome. There's no limit to how many times a selector can be repeated. So long as the offending style doesn't have `!important`, you'll override it eventually.

Comment: As a follow-up, I notice that if I reduce the font size, the arrow size doesn't change.  Any idea why?

Comment: It depends how you implement this change, see updated demo.

Comment: Great, except for me I need to do this:  a.UTF_uparrow.UTF_uparrow.UTF_uparrow.small.  Thanks much.

Comment: Yep you got the idea. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

UTF characters are text, so the `color` property is correct. There must be a rule applying the salmon color with higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

You can use the [Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/UI_Tour) in your browser's dev tools to find which CSS rule is overriding your `a.UTF_uparrow` selector. Check the [Computed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/UI_Tour#Computed_view) tab, which lists all the rules that are applied to the selected element in order of specificity.

```css
a.UTF_uparrow{
    font-size: 15pt;
    color: rgb(140,173,255);
}
```

```html
<a href="#bkmkAA" class="UTF_uparrow" style="text-decoration: none">&#10148;</a>
```

In terms of finding an up arrow, I would recommend that you find an appropriate UTF character rather than trying to rotate this arrow. You can always try an icon font if you don't like the look of any UTF characters. You should also note that UTF characters look different depending on the user's operating system, so you won't achieve a consistent look with them in any case.

Comment: thanks, I'm investigating for an overrride.  But in the Firefox dev console, there is no computed tab.

Comment: Computed is in the Inspector, not the Console. The Inspector is usually the first tab across the top of the dev tools window (opens with F12), to the left of the Console. The first section of the Inspector displays the HTML and the second displays CSS. If you click your `<a href="#bkmkAA" class="UTF_uparrow" style="text-decoration: none">&#10148;</a>` in the HTML section (or use the pointer to highlight it on the page), the CSS section will display the associated CSS rules. I just edited my answer to include a link to more info about the Page Inspector.

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  Using the chain suggested by zer00ne I fixed the problem I have now, but your comments are helpful.